# creating android views by code

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create textview( or similar) dinamicaly, iam a novice and i need your help.
these are parameters recivied from a webservice

```
String jacuzzi=yes   
String estacionamiento = no   
String peli= yes   
String cable=yes  
String roomservice= no  


i need to create them when the (variable == "yes")
```

i´ve benn looking for an answer but i don get it
i dont´know if i really need to create a new layout ,
i am really new in android

here i put my android xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ccccfe"  >

 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp" >

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffd7bd"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_marginLeft="-200dp "

        android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#000000" android:shadowColor="#8a6603"
   android:shadowDx="3" android:shadowDy="2" android:shadowRadius="1.8"
        android:src="@drawable/muestra2" />

    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Motel: "
        android:textColor="#303f46"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"

        android:background="#ccccfe"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="1dp"/>

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableRow >
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow >

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dirección: "
        android:textColor="#303f46"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="90dp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#373737"/>              

 </TableRow>

  <TableRow >
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#303f46"
      android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="90dp"
        android:text="Comuna: " />

     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#373737" />



    </TableRow>

  <TableRow >
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#303f46"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         android:width="90dp"
        android:text="Descripcion: " />

     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#373737" />

    </TableRow>

  <TableRow >

     <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#303f46"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Telefono: "
          android:width="90dp" />

      <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/telefono"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#373737" />

     </TableRow>

   <TableRow >
      <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#303f46"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Correo: " 
        android:width="90dp"/>

       <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/correo"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#373737" />


     </TableRow> 
     <TableRow>
       <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#303f46"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="SitioWeb:" 
        android:width="90dp" />

        <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/sitio"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#373737" />
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to dynamically create your layout using code rather than XML.

First you should give an id to your LinearLayout in your xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myLayout">
```

Then in your code:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

if (variable.contentEquals("yes")) {
    TextView jacuzzi = new TextView(this);
    jacuzzi.setText("jacuzzi");
    myLayout.addView(jacuzzi);
}
```

However avoid using Strings and setting them to yes. Use booleans instead.

Comment: y tried to implemnts your code, but doesn't show anything on the screen.

Comment: You're welcome. @user1676486 thanks for the edits. And I agree about the booleans.

Answer (score 1):

Best to create them and drop them if NOT needed rather than the other way round as shown below.

Firstly

```
boolean jacuzzi = true;
boolean estacionamiento = false;  
boolean peli = true; 
boolean cable = true;  
boolean roomservice = false;
```

Use booleans rather than Strings. boolean can either be true or false. Easier to work with then having yes or no.

// if you must use strings

Use

```
if (jacuzzi.contentEquals("yes")
```

instead of booleans below.

//

I'm going to show you for jacuzzi, use the same technique for all.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

I've called it tv, but you can call it anything. As for the R.id.textView1 - this is referencing to your TextView in your XML code that android automatically called textView1 but you can change this by changing the ID.

```
if(jacuzzi == false)
{tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
```

This reads if jacuzzi is false then make the TextView disappear. You can also use

```
if(!jacuzzi)
{tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
```

As they mean the same thing.

Otherwise for dynamically coding, it's a lot harder. You need to reference your linearlayout by findViewById similarly to how I did the textview. Then you need to create a new textview. If you feel you really want to learn how to do this it's harder but just ask.

Comment: unfortunately those variables comes from a webservice in String..
thanks for your response

Comment: You're still better off using them to set booleans. I.e. use if(jacuzzi.contentEquals("yes"){ bjacuzzi = true; } else {bjacuzzi = false; }

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the tick. And no problem, updated it to help you!

Comment: thanks my friend for your patient, you should be a teacher
regards from chile